# React native + Android Activity onPause/onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, react-native

I have js code with a next emitter:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardWillShow1', function(e: Event) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

How I can emit this event from Activity `onPause`/`onResume`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send event from java using `RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit` method defined here: [DeviceEventManagerModule.java#L27](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/DeviceEventManagerModule.java#L27)

To do it you first need to have reference to `ReactApplicationContext`, then call:

```
reactAppContext
  .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
  .emit("keyboardWillShow1", null);
```

Instead of "null" you can send arbitrary data that will then be attached to the event you receive on JS side.

See this [DeviceEventManagerModule.java#L49](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/DeviceEventManagerModule.java#L49) as an example - this is how back button events are being send to JS.

You can then use similar pattern to dispatch events from activity `onPause`/`onResume` assuming you have reference to `ReactApplicationContext`

Another way would be to create your custom module, which can register for receiving lifecycle events. See how it's done in "Timing" module:

1. "Timing" module implements [LifecycleEventListener.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/LifecycleEventListener.java#L15) interface
2. When module is initialized it registers itself to receive  lifecycle through that interface [Timing.java#L126](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/Timing.java#L126)
3. You can implement `onHostPause` and `onHostResume` methods of that interface and use the snippet from the above to dispatch events from there

Comment: Thank you!  I've been looking all over for how to implement onPause and onResume!

Answer (score 1):

I believe now the [react-native-activity-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-activity-android) module accomplishes this.